# How to find breakup date of a post from several rows

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with following structure for about 1000 Posts

```
SRL     Post_Name   Name                    Start_Date  End_Date    Reason
441a    Lecturer    Dr (Ms)Prem Kali Sharma 01-11-1974  02-03-1989  Retired
441b    Lecturer    Post Vacant             03-03-1989  31-07-1989  Vacant
441c    Lecturer    Dr Aditya Prachandiya   01-08-1989  30-07-1994  Worked1
441d    Lecturer    Dr Aditya Prachandiya   01-08-1994  31-07-1999  Worked2
441e    Lecturer    Dr Aditya Prachandiya   01-08-1999  25-08-2000  Worked1
441f    Lecturer    Dr Aditya Prachandiya   26-08-2000  05-03-2010  Leave
441g    Lecturer    Dr Aditya Prachandiya   06-03-2010  30-06-2016  Retired
441h    Lecturer    Post Vacant             01-07-2016  06-11-2017  Vacant
441i    Lecturer    Dr (Ms) Ranjana Pandey  07-11-2017  06-11-2018  Temporary
442a    Reader      Dr HC Gupta             01-07-1958  30-06-1990  Retired
442b    Reader      Post Vacant             01-07-1990  25-10-1990  Vacant
442c    Reader      Dr Agam Prasad Tyagi    26-10-1990  25-10-1995  Worked5
442d    Reader      Dr Agam Prasad Tyagi    26-10-1995  25-10-2000  Worked1
442e    Reader      Dr Agam Prasad Tyagi    26-10-2000  05-12-2003  Worked2
442f    Reader      Dr Agam Prasad Tyagi    06-12-2003  30-06-2029  Working
```

Basically what i would like to do is have an access query to find if there is any date gap from '441a to 441i' and '442a to 442f'  to check typing error of dates.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). You have Sample data, but the Expected result is unclear.

Comment: A subquery to pull value from another record might be useful. http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord Otherwise, build VBA procedure.

Comment: And since you are showing international date format, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Answer (score 0):

Need to extract the numeric prefix as a group identifier. I created a Calculated field in table with expression: `Left([SRL],3)`. Then a nested query to pull the Start_Date of next record:

> SELECT *, End_Date + 1 AS NextStart, (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.Start_Date
>   FROM Table1 AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.SRL_Group = Table1.SRL_Group AND
>   Dupe.SRL > Table1.SRL) AS NextRecStart
>   FROM Table1;

If NextStart and NextRecStart are not equal then there is a date gap.